# Xamarin Android - Task.Run vs Task.Factory.StartNew and Thread.CurrentPrincipal

Tags: c#, xamarin.android, mono, async-await

I have an Xamarin.Android project, TargetFramework = Android version: 8.0 (Oreo).

I have noticed the following problem:

1. Set `Thread.CurrentPrincipal` to a Custom principal (being extra careful to ensure it is serializable!)
2. Call `await Task.Run()` to run some Task.
3. Within the `Task`, if it executes on a different Thread, the Thread.CurrentPrincipal is not set.
4. If you use Task.Factory.StartNew() instead of Task.Run() then the Task that runs on the background thread does have Thread.CurrentPrincipal set correctly.

In other words, Task.Factory.StartNew seems to flow the CurrentPrinciple to new threads, where as Task.Run doesn't

Furthermore if you repeat this test on NET 4.7, Thread.CurrentPrincipal flows correctly in both scenarios, so this difference in behavior only appears when running on Mono / Xamarin.Android.

Here is a test case:

```
    [Fact]
    public async Task LoginService_WhenUserLogsIn_PrincipalFlowsToAsyncTask()
    {    

        var mockIdentity = new MockIdentity(true);
        var mockPrincipal = new MockPrincipal(mockIdentity);          
        Thread.CurrentPrincipal = mockPrincipal ;          

        await Task.Factory.StartNew(async () =>
        {
            var newThreadId = Thread.CurrentThread.ManagedThreadId; // on different thread.
            Assert.True(Thread.CurrentPrincipal.Identity.IsAuthenticated);
            Assert.Equal(mockPrincipal, Thread.CurrentPrincipal);

            await Task.Factory.StartNew(() =>
            {
                 // still works even when nesting..
                newThreadId = Thread.CurrentThread.ManagedThreadId;
                Assert.True(Thread.CurrentPrincipal.Identity.IsAuthenticated);
                Assert.Equal(mockPrincipal, Thread.CurrentPrincipal);

            }, TaskCreationOptions.LongRunning);

        }, TaskCreationOptions.LongRunning);

        await Task.Run(() =>
        {
           // Following works on NET4.7 and fails under Xamarin.Android.
            var newThreadId = Thread.CurrentThread.ManagedThreadId;
            Assert.True(Thread.CurrentPrincipal.Identity.IsAuthenticated);
            Assert.Equal(mockPrincipal, Thread.CurrentPrincipal);

        });

    }
```

Here are some screenshots whilst debugging under Xamarin.Android application, showing the following things at different points:

1. The Thread.CurrentPrinicpal
2. The Thread.CurrentThread.ManagedThreadId
3. TaskScheduler.Default
4. TaskScheduler.Current
5. TaskScheduler.FromCurrentSynchronizationContext();

This is what things look like prior to StartNew():

[image]

Here is what things look like inside `StartNew()`:

[image]

Note that, the Task scheduled via StartNew() is executing on a thread pool thread, and the ShcnronisationContext TaskScheduler is null because there is no current Synchronisation Context at this point. However, also note that the principal of the thread is set correctly to "Daz" identity.

Here is what things look like, after awaiting Task.Factory.StartNew() and before calling Task.Run():

[image]

Note that we are back on the main thread again, just like we were prior to calling StartNew().

However it appears the SyncContext TaskScheduler has changed (it's ID is now 3). Not sure if that is relevant to this problem.

Now this is what things look like during Task.Run():

[image]

Note: The Thread.CurrentPrincipal.IdentityName has been lost (i.e because the Prinicpal has not flowed to this thread as it did with StartNew().

We are still on a background thread, just like we were with StartNew().
There is no SynchronisationContext on this thread, which is what we expect with a background thread, and was the same within StartNew() so no difference there.
The Default and Current task schedulers look the same (both ID = 1) so no difference there either.

The only difference I can see, is that the Principal has not flowed to the thread.

What is the reason? Is this a bug? I thought Thread.CurrentPrinicpal should always flow with the ExecutionContext when using Task.Run().

I have also raised an issue on Github here: https://github.com/xamarin/xamarin-android/issues/1130

UPDATE: It looks like this has been acknowledged as a bug, hopefully it will be fixed with: https://github.com/mono/mono/pull/6326/files

Comment: In your `StartNew` you're still on the same `SyncContext` as before i.e. the request thread. Unless otherwise specified `StartNew` executes on the current `SycnContext`. `Task.Run` however runs on a default context, i.e. background thread, and you see your principle is not brought with.

Comment: @JSteward - in my `StartNew` it is running on a threadpool thread, and there is no SynchronizationContext. The Thread's CurrentPrincipal is set correctly so it has flowed from the calling thread. However within Task.Run() I can see it is also executing on a background thread, however the Thread.CurrentPrincipal has not been set. This is my problem, because running this exactly the same under .NET4.7 the same things happen, except the Thread.CurrentPrincipal is set correctly in both scenarios. So why is it different under Mono (Xamarin,Android) is my real question.

Comment: @JSteward i have added screenshots showing more detail around what the threads / schedulers / sync context looks like at the various points.

Answer (score 0):

**Edit Begin:**

I will leave the rest of my answer although anyone reading this should note that it is not relevant to the question and I don't mind it hanging as unanswered but please don't mark it down.  There is communication below it that may be relevant.

I have looked closer at the question and realize what is being asked and can honestly agree that I feel this may be a bug.  I cannot explain it and feel this is good to know moving forward.  I'm going to keep an eye on this question for a resolution myself.

**Edit End:**

I'm not entirely sure I understand what you're doing.  Using break points maybe and hovering over the variables?  Place those variables outside of the two tasks and then look at them after they have ran.

But here's the answer I think you're looking for.  When entering Foo it is just an async method with a Task return type.  Yes this means we can await it when called but nothing awaits until it actually runs on a new thread.  Therefore you remain on whatever context calls `await Foo()` until Foo reaches the `await Task.Factory.StartNew`.

Calling `Task.Factory.StartNew` grabs a thread from the thread pool and performs the passed action on that thread.  Once complete it is scheduled to return to `Foo` on the same context it was called on.  Now that context waits again for `await Task.Run` which does exactly the same thing as `await Task.Factory.StartNew`.  You're going to get a thread, from the thread pool, and run the work there etc.

There is only one difference in the two calls and that's the `TaskCreationOptions.LongRunning` parameter passed to the TaskFactory... honestly what the factory does isn't concrete or the same in all environments but it's there to let the factory know that your thread will be alive for a longer period of time.  I believe in Windows it pulls the thread from a different pool of threads meant to run for a longer time but I'm not completely sure.  Either way; you're still on a new thread for each call, not the same thread, and you're back on the same thread in between.

Also, you can use `.ConfigureAwait(false);` at the end of your `await` calls but this will NOT return to the calling context.  It will schedule the thread to continue running on whatever is optimal at the time which may cause issues if you're not aware.  It is more efficient overall but make sure the rest of your method doesn't need to be in the same context to operate.

Hope this helps.

Comment: Thanks I will updated my question to try and describe it more clearly. All I am doing is setting the current threads principal, and then noting that when calling Task.Run() the principal doesn't flow to the thread that the task executes on (unless it happens to have been scheduled to run on the current thread) - however then calling Task.Factory.StartNew() - the prinipal DOES flow to the new thread. This behavior is only happening on Xamarin Android (mono). On full NET framework 4.7 the principal flows correctly in both cases. I would like to know if this is a bug.

Comment: I have added a hopefully more in depth explaination, with screenshots of the various points whilst debugging.

Comment: @Darrell  Hey Darrell, I've updated my answer, which isn't an answer, and appreciate you updating the question.  I see exactly what you're saying now and didn't realize this myself.  I also decided to dig a little and I think you're right this is a bug.  Very odd... I've marked up the answer and placed it as a favorite because I want to follow it for an answer myself.